# Uniqueness of stationary distribution for irreducible Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Theorem 5.5.11 in [Durrett](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) says: "If $p$ is irreducible and has stationary distribution $\pi$, then $\pi(x)=\frac{1}{E_x[T_x]}$." Here $T_x$ is the first positive time the Markov chain visits state $x$, so $E_x[T_x]$ is the expected time to return to state $x$ starting in state $x$. This would imply that the stationary distribution $\pi$ is unique.

However, I noticed the proof of this theorem cites Theorem 5.5.9, which says "If $p$ is irreducible **and recurrent** (i.e., all states are) then the stationary measure is unique up to constant multiples." So is the recurrence assumption also necessary for Theorem 5.5.11?

I believe I have a counterexample if we do not add that assumption. Equation 5.6.1 says that 
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(x,y) \to \frac{\rho_{xy}}{E_y[T_y]} \text{ as } n \to \infty$$
where $\rho_{xy}=P_x(T_y<\infty)$.
I used this to show that $\pi_x(y):=\frac{\rho_{xy}}{E_y[T_y]}$ defines a stationary distribution for every $x$.* Since $\rho_{xy}$ is not necessarily $1$, even when $p$ is irreducible, I believe this provides a counterexample to Theorem 5.5.11 unless we add the assumption that $p$ is recurrent. Is this correct?

---

*I have concerns about this step. It seems obviously false for, e.g., simple random walk in on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ where $E_y[T_y]=\infty$ for all $y$, so $\pi_x(y)=0$ for all $x$. My proof is as follows:

\begin{align*}
\sum_x \pi_z(x)p(x,y) &= \sum_x \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x) p(x,y)\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n \sum_x p^m(z,x)p(x,y)\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n p^{m+1}(z,y)\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,y)\\
&=\pi_z(y).
\end{align*}
This proves $\pi_z(\cdot)$ is stationary. To prove it sums to $1$, note for all $n$:
$$\sum_x \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{m=1}^n \sum_x p^m(z,x) = 1$$
so,
\begin{align*}
\sum_x \pi_z(x)&=\sum_x \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x)\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_x  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x)\\
&=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Sticking with irreducible chains... do you understand that being positive recurrent is the same thing as having a stationary distribution that sums to one or even finite expected time until return to a single state in this communicating class?

Comment: Well my question is how that can be reconciled with my proof, which seems to show positive recurrence is not necessary. I believe there must be a mistake somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: a big issue is your 'proof' interchanges limits without any justification.  Why should be it the case that $\sum_x \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x)
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_x  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(z,x)$  ?

Comment: So is it fair to say that for an irreducible chain $\pi_z(\cdot)$ always defines a stationary *measure* but not a stationary distribution? And if it defines a stationary distribution, then in fact the chain is positive recurrent and that stationary distribution is unique?

Comment: That does not look like a standard definition.  Recurrent irreducible chains have an invariant measure -- denoted e.g. $u_i$ in Feller vol 1.  $\pi_i$ is a probability so $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$.  I can't speak to all books out there, but $\mathbf \pi$ is pretty hardwired to be a probability vector.  Overloading fundamental notation generally results in confusion.

Comment: I apologize, by $\pi_z(y)$ I just mean the quantity $\frac{\rho_{xy}}{E_y[T_y]}$. I called it $\pi$ in my answer because I believed it was a probability distribution. Is it correct to say that for every $z$ this defines a stationary measure of the chain?

Comment: this still doesn't really make sense in the null recurrent irreducible case where necessarily $E_y[T_y]=\infty$

Comment: In that case I would interpret $\frac{\rho_{xy}}{E_y[T_y]}$ to be zero. This is consistent with the limit definition $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{m=1}^n p^m(x,y)$ which is zero if $y$ is null recurrent.

Comment: Look, it's trivially true that $\mathbf x^T P = \mathbf x^T$ when $\mathbf x := \mathbf 0$ but selecting $\mathbf x: =\mathbf u$ where $u_i \geq 0$ and $\mathbf u \neq \mathbf 0$ still is an invariant measure for all irreducible null recurrent chains.  When you talk about an invariant measure people are thinking of $u_i$.  There is a lot of subtlety at play and you'll need to carefully go through a text or two.  It's classical and cheap -- I still recommend Feller vol 1 3rd edtion for this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that book.

Comment: My university library only has the 1st and 2nd edition of this book, which doesn't seem to define this $u_i$ you're talking about. Could you tell me how $u_i$ is defined or point me to another reference?

Comment: I have a copy of the 2nd edition as well.  I was surprised to see it's only mentioned in passing on p. 376 of 2nd edition *"It has been shown... that in an irreducible chain with null states the equations for stationary distributions admit of a unique solution ($v_k$) such that $\sum v_k=\infty$... the modern theory pays increasing attention"* to this.  That said, this is a somewhat esoteric rabbit hole and I'm not sure it's a great use of your time.  As before: $v_i \geq 0$, not all zero, and $\mathbf v^T P = \mathbf v^T$ -- but for a nullrecurrent irreducible chain $\sum_k v_k=\infty$

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I've found Durrett to be a little difficult to piece together, but I found J.R. Norris has a nice book on Markov Chains that specifically focuses on the countably infinite case and lays out the results nicely.